# What exactly spring-data-mongodb do when calls modelRepository.save()?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

For example I have a model:

```
@Document(collection = "events")
public class Event {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String value1;
    private Spring value2;
}
```

And some code in the service class:

```
Event event = eventRepository.findOne("1");
event.setValue1("newValue1");
eventRepository.save(event);
```

Does Spring Data update all fields for the document or only changed fields?
In this case what's about field2, will it be updated with the old value?

How can I turn on logs to check what exactly spring data do?

```
logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate=DEBUG
```

This one turn on logs for the query only, not for the update:

```
016-10-10 09:39:25.938 DEBUG 11417 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : findOne using query: { "_id" : "1"} in db.collection: t87.events
2016-10-10 09:39:25.965 DEBUG 11417 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : Saving DBObject containing fields: [_class, _id, value1, value2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MongoRepository.save()` calls MongoDB [db.collection.save](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/) behind the scenes . Depending on the value of `id` it may insert / upsert / replace the **entire** document.

So, in answer to your question:

> > Does Spring Data update all fields for the document or only changed fields? In this case what's about field2, will it be updated with the old value?

All fields are updated (upserted) including field-2 with the old value.

In order to set only field-1 - which is more efficient - you will have to use `MongoTemplate` in conjunction with an `Update` and a `$set` operator.

In order to see what's going on, you better look at the MongoDB log to see how update operations being handled. See [setProfilingLevel](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/) on how to do capture each write operation; you will probably have to record each operation by setting the profiling level to 2. Don't forget to turn it off afterwards.